# createPDF() - выдает ошибку. ITextRenderer()

Tags: java

Необходимо сгенерировать *Pdf*-файл из *html*-файла.

Использую следующие библиотеки: `itextpdf-5.4.0`, `core-renderer-R8`.

*Eclipse* подсвечивает следующее `renderer.createPDF(os);` и пишет в подсказке

> The method createPDF(OutputStream) from the type ITextRenderer refers to the missing type DocumentException

При компиляции ругается этим:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
>
> The type com.lowagie.text.DocumentException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>
> The method createPDF(OutputStream) from the type ITextRenderer refers to the missing type DocumentException at q.test.main(test.java:32)

Как это исправить?

Собственно, мой код:

```
package q;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
 
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.*;
 
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
 
public class test {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
            
            String File_To_Convert = "Index2.html";
            String url = new File(File_To_Convert).toURI().toURL().toString();
            System.out.println(""+url);
            String HTML_TO_PDF = "ConvertedFile.pdf";
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(HTML_TO_PDF);       
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(url);      
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os); 
            os.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, я сам его по примерам использовал, но запись у меня по другому идет:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;

public void save (ObservableList<TotalUltraSWAGRow> ol , File f) 
        throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    PdfPTable pt = createTablePDF(ol);
    Document dc = new Document (PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
    if(f.exists()){
        f.delete();
    }
    PdfWriter.getInstance(dc, new FileOutputStream(f));
    dc.open();
    dc.add(pt);
    dc.close();
    }
```